# Will Ubuntu Edge be available to everyone after the indiegogo campaign?

Tags: ubuntu-edge

I noticed that ubuntu hasn't mentioned this anywhere.  Will the phone be available after it's backed by indiegogo and everyone who backed it gets theirs?  And will it be available through carriers if it will be available?

Answer (score 6):

It says in the campaign under "About our project":

> The Ubuntu Edge is an exclusive production run, available only through
>   Indiegogo. All of the funding we receive goes directly towards
>   producing the device for expected delivery in May 2014. The only
>   pockets getting filled by this campaign will be yours when the handset
>   arrives.

Main statement imho: "exclusive production run, available only through Indiegogo", so the answer is: No, it will probably not.

Answer (score 1):

Now it states under **Quick facts**:

> Exclusive to Indiegogo backers. The Edge will NOT be available to buy
>   at launch.

---

In the video Mark states:

> ...available only to supporters of this campaign.

And the main page under **[FAQ](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge/x/1680448)** it states:

> *What if you fail to reach the funding target?*
>
> We appreciate every bit of support we receive during the 30 days, and
>   every backer will be welcomed into the Ubuntu community. If we don’t
>   reach our target then we will focus only on commercially available
>   handsets and there will **not be an Ubuntu Edge**.

<sub>*emphasis added*</sub>

So either way, no holding out for this one.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it is mentioned in the video, that it *may*  be available later, but I wouldn't really hold my breath for it.