# How to get Ubuntu Phone

Tags: phone, ubuntu-edge

I am late to know about mobile phones based on ubuntu. if I can still get it ??
if it is still possible for me to get it. how?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Phones are almost ready to hit the market. They'll be around very soon.

In your tags, you are referring to the Ubuntu Edge. [It is not available to anyone who did not take part of the (failed) crowdfunding project.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/323342/will-ubuntu-edge-be-available-to-everyone-after-the-indiegogo-campaign?rq=1) That sucks.

You can, of course, install Ubuntu Touch on a Nexus phone or tablet. Or, you can just wait for the [Meizu MX3, Ubuntu Touch edition](http://linuxg.net/meizu-will-present-a-meizu-mx3-phone-running-ubuntu-touch-at-the-mobile-asia-expo-2014/).